# finding sum of salary from employee table

Tags: sql

I'm having the data in data base like in the below.

```
Emp_id Ename Sal 
11      AAA   10
22      BBB   20
33      CCC   30
44      DDD   60
```

Then i want to populate a new column as in the below.

```
Emp_id Ename Sal  New_column
11      AAA   10    10  --> 10+0
22      BBB   20    30  --> 10+20
33      CCC   30    60  --> 10+20+30
44      DDD   60    120 --> 10+20+30+60
```

Thank you for the help in adavance!

Comment: related to window analytic functions and this depends on you're using as DBMS.

Comment: Please always tag SQL requests with the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use Window analytic function within your DBMS, then use :

```
select t.*, sum(sal) over (order by emp_id) as New_column 
  from tab t
 order by emp_id
```

Comment: You should add an `ORDER BY` clause. Otherwise the running total may look weird in your results.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case your RDBMS does not support analytic functions (e.g. because you are using MySQL 5.7 or earlier), we can also use a correlated subquery to find the running totals:

```
SELECT
    Emp_id,
    Ename,
    Sal,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.Sal) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.Emp_id <= t1.Emp_id) AS New_column
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    Emp_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the running sum. If your DB product supports window function, You may try below -

```
SELECT Emp_id
      ,Ename
      ,Sal 
      ,SUM(Sal) OVER(ORDER BY EMP_ID) New_column
FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

Comment: You should add an `ORDER BY` clause. Otherwise the running total may look weird in your results.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query for the running aggregate in `SQL Server`.

```
SELECT Emp_id
    ,Ename
    ,Sal
    ,SUM(Sal) OVER (
        ORDER BY Emp_id
        ) AS New_column
FROM Employee
ORDER BY Emp_Id
```

Comment: This is not limited to SQL Server by the way. This is standard SQL and available in many DBMS.

Comment: you are able to upvote each person from now on as being rep. >= 15 :) @NagaSushmaKallam